# Word 2007 Macro Help

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a school project on typing speed. In order to capture the user's characters per minute, I thought a Word macro would be useful, since they'll be typing only in Word.

I'm not looking to make a full keylogger -- simply something that counts how many characters the user has typed. I've searched for topics like this elsewhere, but they always seem to end with someone responding "We don't support this kind of coding" or something like that.

Could anyone point me towards a useful tutorial? I'm not so good with visual basic.

Comment: You can hook `WindowSelectionChange` and look for `Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP` and capture those changes in a count in a timer. It's not perfect, but it's can get a decent count.

Answer (score 0):

Well, word doesn't support any events to that you could hook into to track WHEN a use actually types characters, which would make it tough to track speed.

About the best you could do in native word macros would be to setup a timer, then, at regular timed intervals (say, every second) grab the activedocument, and check the length of the .content property.

that would be a pretty crude analog for chars per second though.

There's tons of stuff on word macros on the internet, just google "Word VBA examples" for a pile of 'em